# Best practice for single column within row in bootstrap v3 grid system?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've read about the grid system here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid. While the documentation doesn't directly address a scenario in which there's one column within a row, I do see one example of this here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-offsetting > third row of the example code.

Currently, I'm applying the class `.col-xs-12` to the one column within the `<div class="row">` containing tags and it is working well across all viewport dimensions.

However, I want to ensure there isn't a better way to do this.

Answer (score 30):

I think adding a col*-12 will be the best practice. It will make all rows in your grid act the same.

Example:

[image]

**html**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row" style="background-color:yellow;">
      <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:aqua;">col-xs-12 inside a row</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row" style="background-color:yellow;">
      direct inside a row
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row" style="background-color:yellow;">
      <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:red;">col-xs-6 inside a row</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:orange;">col-xs-6 inside a row</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you see the content is NOT in line with the other rows when you don't add a col-*-12 (due to the missing padding). All the rows the same will make future changes easier.

You will have to notice the col*-12 columns differs from the other col-*-* cause the don't have a float left, see: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10152

Comment: that's only because you added a `.row` element. if you were to not use `.col-xs-12`, then you would also not use `.row`. So an argument to use .col-xs-12 would be the parallelism of incorporating `.row`, so that if you want to add columns later on, you don't also have to add `.row`. It minimizes exceptions, and keeps things "parallel"

Comment: @gwho I agree with you that we don't need `.row` here but I think it's better to have `.col-md-12` for left and right padding

Comment: @JitendraVyasI But you dont need `.col-md-12` for the paddings. See, when you use only `.container`, this already have a 15px left and right padding, if you add a `.row` it will remove -15px, and adding a `.col-md-12` will add 15px again.

I do not think it makes sense to use this entire DOM tree, and the more DOM's you have, the more "heavy" your page gets for CSS and Javascript.

Answer (score 12):

Well, if you only have one element and want it to use the full width of the container (1170px) then you probably don't need the .row/.col-xs-12 at all.

See this [Example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/), check out the source code of the page itself.

Notice how the content on top doesn't use rows/cols?

```html
  <div class="container">

  ...

  <h3>Three equal columns</h3>
  <p>Get three equal-width columns <strong>starting at desktops and scaling to large desktops</strong>. On mobile devices, tablets and below, the columns will automatically stack.</p>
```

In this case, the row/cols wouldn't do anything except add negative margin (row) and padding (col).

Also, the example you're pointing out uses offsetting, and is not full width, so the row/col is required.

Answer (score 2):

Just to put a last nail in the coffin, you REALLY need the combo of class `row` + `col-12` for single column layout to keep consistency with other multi-column rows that you may have in your layout. This prevents miss alignment in layouts where a designer may request custom **external gutters that differs from inner column gutter**.

Here's a link to my proof of concept : https://codepen.io/martindubenet/full/OJVwEWv

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late but the answers above didn't consider the [grid offsetting classes](https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.6/docs/css/#grid-offsetting)

You could center a column with something like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3</div>
</div>
```