# Bootstrap Lining Up Form Elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have created a Bootply to show the issue I am having: http://www.bootply.com/8fPmr31Wd7

Scroll down to look at "People" and "Places" and find they are indented along the sides.

Perhaps I am not using the right classes, or perhaps there is a bug with the grid, but if you use the grid commands within a form, it causes the elements that are within a grid to be just a hair off on each side and not line up properly with the rest of the form.

I know Bootstrap 4 is in testing, but I didn't know if this was a bug or something I am missing so I thought I'd ask. Thank you.

Comment: Still interested to know if there is an actual answer to this. Here is my temporary workaround:

`.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:15px;
}`
`.no-gutter > [class*='col-']:first-child {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
`

Comment: You shouldn't have to modify the CSS like this which is akin to hacking out some of the bootstrap Grid system - it's more of a structural issue with the markup. See my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have grid rows that don't contain any columns for all your other form rows, and you're using columns for the People and Places form element groups.

If you add a 12-unit wide column within your other rows, as per the top answer to [Best practice for single column within row in bootstrap v3 grid system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854586/best-practice-for-single-column-within-row-in-bootstrap-v3-grid-system), your horizontal spacing within your grid will be consistent.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I didn't get any notification that I got an answer on this. I have selected your answer as the best answer. It makes sense when you put it that way! Yes, my "hack" was just a temporary thing because I thought I wasn't going to get an answer. Thanks again!